# onLoad iFrame with Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm trying to load an iFrame in to colorbox using an onload event - seems like it should be simple but I'm getting the error "the content failed to load"

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.colorbox({href:"http://www.google.com", open: true});
    }); 
</script>
```

Any ideas as to why this may not be working?

Comment: you try adding iframe: true to the call

Comment: *facepalm" thanks! worked perfectly. Please put it as an answer so I can accept :P.

Comment: colorbox is one of my favourite lightboxes, use it regularly.

Comment: Seems good so far, I'm sure I'll have a few more mishaps but seems like a lot of people use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add iframe: true to the function call

Answer (score 3):

I made [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/TKHbJ/) to test that issue, and concluded that it has a weird behavior when the width and the height are not set, so this way I did solved the issue:

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.colorbox({
    iframe      : true,
    innerWidth  : 425,
    innerHeight : 344,
    href        : "http://www.youtube.com/embed/617ANIA5Rqs?rel=0&wmode=transparent"
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the same but setting width and height sorted the problem :).